# Create a Maven Plugin that performs parameterised JUnit Tests

Tags: java, oracle, maven, junit

We have a multimodule Maven project and intend on performing tests on this. Because our tests are very homogenous, instead of writing the same test over and over, we wrote a parameterised test, which fetches all the files which stand to test and runs its tests against them. Now we want this as a maven plugin so you could just do something like `mvn xquerytestrunner:test`

I created a separate project, created a Java File in there and annotated it with

```
 @Mojo( name = "xquerytester")
 public class XQueryTestRunner extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter( property = "xquerytester.querytotest", defaultValue = "" )
    private static String queryToTest;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
         JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
         Result result = junit.run(ParameterizedGenericXQueryTest.class);
    }
}
```

Now my question. Will this run? And does it make sense?

My other option was to just have the test in the src/test/java folder of the main module and run it with `mvn -Dtest=TestCircle test` but the problem is that we use a plugin by Oracle ( `oracle-soa-plugin` ) that messes up everything around the project but we have to use it.

Our main pom.xml has `<packaging>pom</packaging>` which is why running the above test goal doesnt work. it just doesnt build or test anything. If i change it to `jar` the plugin throws errors during build. and I cannot skip build phase because the plugin just does its stuff anyways.

My goal is just to have a one liner for the console that runs my parameterized tests. It just seems Oracle didnt read the howtos on how to write a maven plugin and now i have to work with it.

---

#### Update 1:

We now went with a maven plugin. This can be run independent of the oracle soa plugin and also on a mvn project that has a "pom" packagint type.

**The Mojo Class:**

```
@Mojo( name = "xsl")
public class XslTestRunner {

@Parameter( property = "xsl.name", defaultValue = "" )
private static String name;

public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    Result result = junit.run(ParameterizedGenericXslTest.class);
    PrintHelper.printResults(result, TransformationTestType.XQUERY);
}
}
```

**The Maven Plugin Pom:**

In general I followed these instructions: [Your First Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html)

Comment: Why not using JUnit parameterized tests and using maven-surefire for that? What about https://github.com/wgroeneveld/jasmine-junit-runner ?

Comment: we use a parameterized test. but the problem is the Oracle SOA Plugin requires us to have the parent pom to have the packaging type "pom" and this packaging type doesnt do the tests. so im thinking a plugin is required